# Formatting Python Print Statement

Tags: python-3.x, formatting

I used `from __future__ import print_function` on an output that I had put into a list. It removed apostrophes and outer brackets. Below is a snippet of a larger print statement, how would I go a step further to remove the brackets and remove the space between the parenthesis & 378, and float the last element to 2 decimal places?

Code:

```
for key, value in list[:10]:
    if key in dict1:
        if key in dict2:
            if key in dict3:
                list1 = [dict1[key],"(",key,")", dict2[key], dict3[key], value]
                print(*list1)
```

PrintStatement:

```
Evanescence ( 378 ) 513476 [226] [2272.0176991150443]
```

Comment: Share you actual data and `print()` statement.

Comment: I meant to when I made the post, its been a late night.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to construct a list and the expand that list in a print statement, you can directly use `.format()`. It looks like your last 2 items are lists of one value you just need to get the first index `[0]`

```
print("{} ({}) {} {} {:.2f}".format(dict1[key], key, dict2[key], dict3[key][0], value[0]))
```